# Opening solidworks part using python and solidworks api

Tags: python, solidworks, solidworksapi

I am trying to open a solidworks file using python and the solidworks api. I dont seem to understand the solidworks OpenDoc6 documentation. The last line in the following does not work and I get an AttributeError: swDocPART

Does anyone happen to know what is wrong with my code?

```
import win32com.client

# part path and name
filePath = r'\Part1.SLDPRT'

# Connect to SolidWorks and open the document
swApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('SldWorks.Application')

if swApp is None:
    print("Error: Could not connect to SolidWorks")
else:
    print("Success: Connected to SolidWorks")

# Open the SolidWorks document using OpenDoc6
swDoc = swApp.OpenDoc6(filePath, win32com.client.constants.swDocPART, 0, "", 0, 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar enough with Python and how it leverages the SolidWorks API libraries, specifically Enums. However, with .NET we have to convert the enum to an int (ie. `(int)swDocumentType.swDocPART`). In the case of swDocPART, the enum value is 1.

The document type enums can be found here - [https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/swconst/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.swconst~SOLIDWORKS.Interop.swconst.swDocumentTypes_e.html](https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/swconst/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.swconst%7ESOLIDWORKS.Interop.swconst.swDocumentTypes_e.html)